# Why the second IF statement is Unrachable code detected?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> sy;
        public string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            string result = "";
            string key = request.QueryString.GetKey(0);
            if (key == "cmd")
            {
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "upload status")
                {
                    if (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus == "uploading file")
                    {
                        Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
                        return "uploading";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "upload unknown state";
                    }

                    if (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus == "file uploaded successfully")
                    {
                        Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
                        return "upload completed";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "upload unknown state";
                    }
                }
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "nothing")
                {
                    return "Connection Success";
                }
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "start")
                {
                    StartRecrod();
                    result = "Recording started";
                }

                if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop")
                {
                    dirchanged = false;
                    StartRecrod();
                    result = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
                    sy = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                    WatchDirectory();
                    sy.Task.Wait();
                    Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(fileforupload);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = "Nothing have been done";
            }

            return result;

        }
```

This line:

```
if (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus == "file uploaded successfully")
```

The 'if' is with green underline and say Unreachable code detected.
How can i fix it and why it's Unreachable code ?

Maybe i need to use result = and not return ? But that's not seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because above that, you have:

```
if (...)
{
    return "uploading";
}
else
{
    return "upload unknown state";
}
```

Either the `if` or the `else` is true, so the code will return from that block anyway, and the code below it won't be executed.

You have three options, so you seem to be looking for a `switch` which is the most readable in this case:

```
switch (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus)
{   
    case "uploading file":
        Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
        return "uploading";

    case "file uploaded successfully":
        Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
        return "upload completed";

    default:
        return "upload unknown state";
}
```

Or use a dictionary to translate the service statuses to your application statuses, or use `if () else if () else` as suggested by [@Thiago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32398560/266143).

Comment: CodeCaster it's working great. Just one small thing when the status is "upload completed" i want to reset it back to default to "upload unknown state" since i'm checking the status every second i want that once the status is "upload completed" then right after it reset it back to "upload unknown state" i mean make once the return "upload completed" but then right after it reset to default.

Comment: @Harim I'm not sure what you're asking. You could split this out into a `GetStatusMessage(string uploadStatus)` and `SetStatusMessage(string status)` method, then call those from where you want to (re)set the status.

Comment: @Harim I think I get what you mean. I removed the `Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";` for brevity. I have now re-added them under their respective `case`s.

Answer (score 5):

because of your return statement. It will stop the if / else flux. Maybe you're searching for this:

```
if (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus == "uploading file")
                    {
                        Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
                        return "uploading";
                    }
                    else if (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus == "file uploaded successfully")
                    {
                        Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
                        return "upload completed";
                    }                   
                    else
                    {
                        return "upload unknown state";
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus == "uploading file")
                {
                    Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
                    return "uploading";
                    //return may happen here case 1
                }
                else
                {
                    return "upload unknown state";
                    // or here case 2
                }
```

Only two cases are possible.

```
                if (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus == "file uploaded successfully")
```

Transform your code to the following:

```
if (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus == "uploading file")
                {
                    Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
                    return "uploading";
                    //return can happen here. Case 1
                }
                else if(some another condition) // case 2
                {
                    return "upload unknown state";
                    // or here case 2
                }
                //now this code is reachable 
                if (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus == "file uploaded successfully")
```